# Unit testing localStorage with Jasmine & JS

Tags: javascript, jasmine, local-storage

I'm trying to get my head around unit testing `window.localStorage` and I believe I'm almost there, I just can't seem to access the actual key/value pairs when testing my final helper method.

I have the following methods:

```js
export function testSet() {
  window.localStorage.setItem('testSet', '1234');
}

export function testDeletePrefix() {
  let deleted = false;
  Object.entries(window.localStorage).forEach(([key, value]) => {
  console.log(key);
  // This logs out getItem setItem removeItem clear
  if (key.startsWith("test") && key !== "test") {
    window.localStorage.removeItem(key);
    console.log(`Item with key '${key}' deleted from local storage.`);
    deleted = true;
  }
});
  if (!deleted) {
    console.log(`No key starting with 'test' found in local storage.`);
  }
}
```

Unit test:

```js
setItemSpy = spyOn(window.localStorage, "setItem").and.callFake(
    (key, value) => {
      store[key] = value.toString();
    }
  );

testSet();
expect(setItemSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith("testSet", "1234");
testDeletePrefix();
```

Whenever I run this test I get the output `No key starting with 'test' found in local storage.`

So the `spyOn` has confirmed the key/value pair has been set, so why can't I access them when looping over `window.localStorage`?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is the `.and.callFake(`. We are saying that for every time you are called, call this fake implementation and not the real implementation. We need the real implementation for `testDeletePrefix` to have the item in local storage.

Try using `.and.callThrough()` to call the actual implementation.

```
// !! Change this to .and.callThrough() to call the actual implementation
// every time `localStorage.setItem` is called and then the actual implementation
// of localStorage.setItem is called.
setItemSpy = spyOn(window.localStorage, "setItem").and.callThrough();

testSet();
expect(setItemSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith("testSet", "1234");
testDeletePrefix();
```

Comment: Thank you for your advice, I have tried this but still have the same issue

Comment: if i log out `key` in the `testDeletePrefix` method, i get `getItem setItem removeItem clear`

Comment: Very strange, it seems `Object.entries(window.localStorage)` gets the keys of `localStorage.` and not the values of the current `localStorage`. I am not sure why this is, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to post a solution that is now working for me (though if anyone spots something that's not right, please let me know).

I started with creating a `mockLocalStorage` helper:

```
export const mockLocalStorage = {
  data: {},
    setItem: function(key, value) {
      this.data[key] = value;
    },
    getItem: function(key) {
      return this.data[key];
    },
    removeItem: function(key) {
      delete this.data[key];
    },
    clear: function() {
      this.data = {};
    },
    entries: function() {
      return Object.entries(this.data);
    },
  };
```

The in my test spec I have:

```
import { testDeletePrefix } from "../src/my_helper.js";
import { mockLocalStorage } from "./support/mockLocalStorage.js";

describe("deletePrefix", () => {

  beforeEach(() => {
    mockLocalStorage.data = {};
  });

  it("should delete a prefixed item from local storage if it exists", () => {
    // Set the item
    mockLocalStorage.setItem('test123', 'test');

    spyOn(mockLocalStorage, 'removeItem').and.callThrough();
    // Call testDeletePrefix function, passing in localStorage of choice
    testDeletePrefix(mockLocalStorage);

    // Expectations
    expect(mockLocalStorage.removeItem).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    expect(mockLocalStorage.getItem('test123')).toBeUndefined();
  });
});
```

Finally I updated the testDeletePrefix() method to accept an argument, which is the localStorage object, so in test it can be mockLocalStorage and when live a user can pass in window.localStorage:

```
export function testDeletePrefix(localStorage) {
  let deleted = false;
  const entries = localStorage.entries ? localStorage.entries() : Object.entries(localStorage);
  entries.forEach(([key, value]) => {
    if (key.startsWith('test) && key !== 'test) {
      localStorage.removeItem(key);
      deleted = true;
    }
  });
  if (!deleted) {
    console.log(`No key starting with test followed by text found in local storage.`);
  }
}
```